# Json.Net collection deserializing

Tags: .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a JSON string which looks like this in Chrome's Json viewer (part of it):
[image: json]

How do I desarialize it using Json.Net into a collection of simple objects that have a name and a type in them? I don't care about the codes. I tried using json2csharp.com but I get an extremely long list of classes, one for each OP-code. Single class would be ideal.

Edit: OK, I actually need the OP-codes but can get them as another field in each object. So removing them out from the json string is not the solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class SimpleObject
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string Type{get;set;}
}

var simpleObjects =
      JObject.Parse(json).Cast<JToken>()
         .SelectMany(o => o.Select(p =>
                                    new SimpleObject
                                       {
                                          Name = (string)p["Name"],
                                          Type = (string)p["Type"]
                                       }
                                  )
                     );
```